# PowerShell: can't modify environment variables

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I have an environment variable set via "system properties -> advanced -> Environment Variables". I modified the variable's value. In cmd, I see the new value. In [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell), the value is still the old value. Trying to set it with [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerShell will cache its information. Use the Refresh method to solve your problem. I found this in the SQL area too.

Comment: How exactly do I run this method?

Comment: On a normal directory, you should be able to do: `(get-item .).Refresh()` - but that doesn't seem to be available for the Env: folder. Starting a new instance of PowerShell will demonstrate that it's a caching issue - I'm just not sure right now where the Refresh method should live for it. I can query an environment variable called blah using `Get-WmiObject Win32_Environment | where-object -filter {$_.Name -eq 'blah'} | select VariableValue`, and this happily shows me the latest version, even though the cache still hasn't been refreshed for the env: drive. I'll look some more...

Answer (score 0):

Did you launch a new instance of PowerShell?

Every process gets its own environment block when it starts. Typically it gets a copy of the parent process environment block, but CreateProcess can also take a custom one.

This means that changes to the system environment won't affect running processes. So you'll need to start a new one.